# How to stop differently sized pages depending on different computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a webpage that I'm pretty happy with except it looks different on differently sized monitors. The basic idea is that you hover over the words and then they appear and disappear forever. On my laptop, I've made it so that the words go to the edge of the page--so long as it is fullscreen--and then continue on the next line, but I've noticed that this doesn't work properly on differently sized screens. The problem comes with the fact that I'm also using bottom-borders as an aesthetic element. Each line is its own element with its own borders, so that each line of text sits atop a grey bar.

Is there anyway that I can adjust the size of the page or anything to fit differently sized monitors?

CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var exceptions = ["bulls", "rhymes,", "spin", "blinding", "pinched", "oxygen", "tendrils", "exact", "agreement", "combination", "swallow", "smiles",
    "mirror", "treehouse", "project", "dwindling", "laughing", "fall", "stupor", "breaking", "skin", "untimely", "tears", "mutely", "shoelaces",
  ];

  var moreExceptions = ["stolidly", "astronomy", "nymphs", "exist", "ecstasy", "compounds", "music", "rope", "flit", "conjure", "frisked", "rabid"];

  var evenMoreExceptions = ["sky", "astral-flower,", "free", "stupid", "stream", "particle", "echo", "grown", "electron", "Moans", "swig", "huddled", "clearing", "soothsayer", "sylph", "laughing", "technicolor", "stuffed", "chanting", "tearing", "spitting", "sheep"];

  $("p").each(function() { //for all paragraphs

    var txt = $(this).text() //get text, split it up, add spans where necessary, put it back together
      .split(" ")
      .map(function(x) {

        var $word = $("<span>").text(x); //create '<span>'+x+'</span>' as jQuery object
        if (exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase())) {
          return $word.addClass("alwaysVisible").prop("outerHTML"); //return object as a string
        }

        if (moreExceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase())) {
          $word.addClass("hiddenAtFirst"); //special class for words from moreExceptions
        }
        if (evenMoreExceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase())) {
          $word.addClass("hiddenAtFirstAndThen"); //special class for words from evenMoreExceptions
        }
        return $word.addClass("hover").prop("outerHTML");

      }).join(" ");

    $(this).html(txt); //set the text to our newly manipulated text

  }).on("mouseout", ".hover", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover"); // without .hover it will reappear again 

    //if it's from moreException list
    if ($(this).hasClass("hiddenAtFirst")) {
      $(this).addClass("alwaysVisible"); //make it alwaysVisible
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass("hiddenAtFirstAndThen")) {
      $(this).fadeOut(40000);
      $(this).addClass("hover");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: black
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10% opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* VISIBLE */

.alwaysVisible,
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.instructions {
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% {
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  }
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.instructions {
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% {
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  }
}

p {
  /* set the animation on p which is the element that have the border */
  -webkit-animation: p 3s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="NarrativeTheory.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="NarrativeTheory.js"></script>
  <div class="instructions">
    Place your cursor directly below the arrow, and follow the lines left-to-right. Fullscreen your browser for best effect.
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="arrow.png">

  <br>

  <div class=s tory>

    <p>
      "Do you see it?" The Grandmaster calls out, "The Second </p>
    <p> Star?" James did not see the Second Star, not even through the </p>
    <p> telescope, but then again he was never very good at spotting </p>
    <p> constellations. He remembers how his neighbor used to point </p>
    <p> them out to him during neighborhood barbeques. Bulls and </p>
    <p> lions so stolidly sitting in the sky. Those beasts you often hear </p>
    <p> about in the Bible. When you actually saw them-at the zoo </p>
    <p> or something-they looked quite pitiable and stupid. This is not </p>
    <p> like that; this is science. No mythologies, characters or </p>
    <p> rhymes; only astronomy and physics. "We see it!" Calls out </p>
    <p> a young woman, about his own age. Her voice is smooth and </p>
    <p> bursting with piety. She and some other folks are dancing </p>
    <p> around, giddy at the coming transformation. She's not </p>
    <p> extraordinarily pretty-none of them are really-but the glow of </p>
    <p> their joy, the pure bliss that shines off of them in every </p>
    <p> direction makes fine nymphs out of them. The childish spirits </p>
    <p> spin around and giggle, jumping like stray flames from the </p>
    <p> bonfire that had burned earlier. He admires them deeply. </p>
    <p> He is a very large man, and although he has been working</p>
    <p> toward letting his spirit fly free, he is not yet able to dance </p>
    <p> with such blaze. "Come here children! Settle down!" The </p>
    <p> Grandmaster shouts, wiping his brow. "Do you know why we </p>
    <p> live out here?" he pauses, seemingly inhabited by some </p>
    <p> wayward astral-flower, and sniffs. "Well, alright I'll tell you. </p>
    <p> You see, the city is blinding; wayward light leaks from every </p>
    <p> window." His voice softens, and he looks at us as a father </p>
    <p> would, "And so here we are, come to a place of peace; where </p>
    <p> the infinite pinched points of the universe, stream along in a </p>
    <p> dance of profound revelry. Where power doesn't exist except </p>
    <p> for the collective power. Come to me. Let's hold each other </p>
    <p> now." Two women rush to either side of the Grandmaster </p>
    <p> eagerly, as if trying to catch a butterfly. The whole group grabs </p>
    <p> ahold of each other, however they can. Even though there are </p>
    <p> at least eleven people between him and the Grandmaster, </p>
    <p> James can still feel the tendrils of energy reach him through </p>
    <p> the others. It feels warm and exact. His body reverberates with </p>
    <p> the excitation. He feels himself drawing closer to the </p>
    <p>
      frequency of their leader-the Natural Frequency. "The light is </p>
    <p> coming to carry us children! We shall soon ascend and </p>
    <p> transcend. As both particle and wave we will rise from this </p>
    <p> earth. As the ultimate purveyor of knowledge-we shall </p>
    <p> become light itself, if only we prepare our bodies to reach the </p>
    <p> Natural Frequency." His face and voice darken at once, "While </p>
    <p> the unattuned become the less than dark, the nothing they have </p>
    <p> always secretly known themselves to be." Moans of agreement </p>
    <p> and ecstasy echo between the Children and the Grandmaster.</p>
    <p> The energy compounds between them. The Resonance is </p>
    <p> beginning. The Second Star and the First Star have grown </p>
    <p> closer. They are almost exactly seven light-years apart now. </p>
    <p> The Grandmaster tells them that this is the perfect distance </p>
    <p> away. Tonight the combination of their light will produce the </p>
    <p> Perfect Wave, a wave of light that contains frequencies in </p>
    <p> perfect alignment with the frequency of both an electron and</p>
    <p> a proton-the Natural Frequency. The rest of the world will </p>
    <p> fade, but the Children will join the light due to their perfect </p>
    <p> attunement. "The world is so dark," the Grandmaster begins </p>
    <p> again, sobbing, "It's so dark. It's just not fair." The rest of the </p>
    <p> group begins to cry as well. Their passionate moans have </p>
    <p> turned to despairing wails. James too sheds a few tears. He </p>
    <p> couldn't convince them. They wouldn't come with him. "We </p>
    <p> tried to free them Children. We really did try our best. But it's </p>
    <p> time to go. Let's swallow them down and begin the </p>
    <p> Attunement." James looks at the Attunement Agent in his </p>
    <p> hand, designed by the Grandmaster himself to allow the </p>
    <p> frequencies of his body to merge with the Natural Frequency. </p>
    <p> He puts the pill in his mouth, and takes a swig from the </p>
    <p> water bottle that someone has evidently handed him. As he </p>
    <p> throws his head back to swallow the pill, he sees the stars, </p>
    <p> mutely dinging in the sky. He feels very, very good now.</p>
    <p>**************************************************************************************************************************************************************</p>
    <p> James wakes up. There is still a world. He is not light, but he </p>
    <p> is still something. He misses the feeling he felt before. Again </p>
    <p> hungry for the flesh of imagined sweetings, he rises to his feet. </p>
    <p> They feel very heavy. He takes off his shoes and ties the </p>
    <p> shoelaces together and they dangle from his fingertips, like </p>
    <p> dice on a rear view mirror, as he wanders through a forest </p>
    <p> unknown to him. He moves towards what little bonfire smoke </p>
    <p> remained from the campsite. The sun is up, but just barely. As </p>
    <p> he walks he sees the other children, some of them huddled </p>
    <p> together, still sleeping, with smiles on their faces. Others look </p>
    <p> a lot like him, wandering around aimlessly. He is too afraid to </p>
    <p> speak to them. The energy is gone. They are all still here. We </p>
    <p> are all still here. Very still. Where is the grandmaster? Has he </p>
    <p> ascended? If he had ascended, why are the children still here? </p>
    <p> Why is everything still here? He comes out of the woods, into </p>
    <p> the clearing where they have built their houses. There is no </p>
    <p> music playing, as there so often was. It is beginning to rain. </p>
    <p> Good for the crops. He eyes the grandmaster's treehouse. He has </p>
    <p> never been there. Grandmaster always told them that they </p>
    <p> should not visit his lodging unless it was an absolute </p>
    <p> emergency. And even then, if Daydream was available, they </p>
    <p> were supposed to tell her and she was to summon him. But if </p>
    <p> there ever was an emergency, this was it. Striding towards the </p>
    <p> abode of the mistaken soothsayer, he tries to project confidence </p>
    <p> as best as he can, but he is sure it is not working. He arrives at </p>
    <p> the bottom of the rope ladder, and calls up to the grandmaster. </p>
    <p> "Grandmaster!" He is surprised to hear his own voice; he had </p>
    <p>not heard it by itself for so long. It does not sound the way that </p>
    <p> he remembered it. But there is no response. He yells louder, but </p>
    <p> still no reply. He looks around warily, seeing only wayward </p>
    <p> children still dwindling around the edge of the woods, unsure of </p>
    <p> how to continue. He drops his shoes and takes a step onto the </p>
    <p>
      ladder. He struggles even to balance on the first rung, but </p>
    <p> pushes up. Swinging back and forth, he forces himself to reach </p>
    <p> the top. He places his elbows on the floorboards, and peers </p>
    <p> through the open door. There the grandmaster sits. His throat </p>
    <p> laughing blood, Daydream sleeping forever in his arms. James </p>
    <p> falls. It's about a six foot drop. Nothing terrible, but air seems </p>
    <p> to flit away from him with each breath now. He lays on his </p>
    <p> back. The oxygen is coming back to him, a tempestuous sylph </p>
    <p> seeming sometimes to tempt him with an especially full breath</p>
    <p> before teasing away again. But as he lays, it comes back to him. </p>
    <p> It gets easier and by the end he breathes easily, his own form of </p>
    <p> meditation. Some time passes, he is not sure how much, before </p>
    <p> he rises to his feet. He is not sure whether he is in shock, but the </p>
    <p> pain of the fall seems to have displaced the horror of what he </p>
    <p> had seen. He goes back to his quarters, an old school bus that he </p>
    <p> shares with about eight other men as living quarters. The </p>
    <p> steering wheel was still attached, but the bus did not drive. Idly, </p>
    <p> he sits and gives the steering wheel a turn or two. One man lays </p>
    <p> on his mat, blissful and unconscious, like a stuffed animal. He </p>
    <p> must have made his way back in the technicolor stupor. Habit is </p>
    <p> a powerful hand to hold. Again, James is too afraid to wake </p>
    <p> him, too afraid to speak to him. He does not know these people. </p>
    <p> He only knows the grandmaster, and he has gone. James sits </p>
    <p> incredulous in the seat of the bus. A riddling strand of accordion </p>
    <p> rain weeps across the window, leaving behind it a trail of </p>
    <p>
      self-fragments before breaking up into nothing. The silence </p>
    <p> which at first oppressed him, seemed to conjure up a kind of </p>
    <p> peace within him now. There was no silence before. No matter </p>
    <p> how early you woke up. Always people singing, yelling, </p>
    <p> chanting their mantras, or perhaps the grandmaster would be </p>
    <p> giving a sermon. He had a booming voice, one that really got </p>
    <p> under your skin and frisked your spirit. But now, the noise </p>
    <p> subsided, James can think again. He thinks first about how he </p>
    <p> has no wallet, no ID, no social security number, no cellphone </p>
    <p> and how there’s no landline. He then thinks about how he's not </p>
    <p> sure how to get home, or if there still is a home. He hasn't talked </p>
    <p> to his mother or father in years. They probably would not have </p>
    <p> missed him anyway. What is there for him, out there? But then, </p>
    <p> what is here? He peers out the window. It seems that the </p>
    <p> children have discovered the untimely death of the grandmaster. </p>
    <p> They are tearing anything and everything apart. They are </p>
    <p> pulling the crops up, biting them and then spitting them onto </p>
    <p> the ground. The shepherd has gone, and the sheep have grown </p>
    <p> rabid in his absence. James isn't quite sure what to do. So he </p>
    <p> just holds the steering wheel of the old school bus, and turns it. </p>
    <p> Round and round, round and round.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a `div` in your `head`.

Comment: @hungerstar are there no `div`s allowed in the `head`? How else could I format the text in the head? Should I just move it to the body?

Comment: That is correct. You need to put it in your page. `head` can only have [**metadata content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content). Basically the `head` is where you config your page a bit, include resources. Its contents are not meant to be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one thing keeping your page from doing what you expect it to and it's this:

`**************************************************************************************************************************************************************`

This is essentially one ***really long*** word. By default words don't break on their own so it's stretching out parent and ancestor elements, making your page wider than you'd like.

Remove this line, replace it with something else or apply `word-break: break-word;` to the element containing all the asterisks.

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {

  var alwaysVisible = [
        "bulls", "rhymes,", "spin", "blinding", "pinched",
        "oxygen", "tendrils", "exact", "agreement", "combination",
        "swallow", "smiles", "mirror", "treehouse", "project",
        "dwindling", "laughing", "fall", "stupor", "breaking",
        "skin", "untimely", "tears", "mutely", "shoelaces"
      ],
      hiddenAtFirst = [
        "stolidly", "astronomy", "nymphs", "exist", "ecstasy",
        "compounds", "music", "rope", "flit", "conjure",
        "frisked", "rabid"
      ],
      hiddenAtFirstAndThen = [
        "sky", "astral-flower,", "free", "stupid", "stream",
        "particle", "echo", "grown", "electron", "Moans",
        "swig", "huddled", "clearing", "soothsayer", "sylph",
        "laughing", "technicolor", "stuffed", "chanting", "tearing",
        "spitting", "sheep"
      ];

  $( 'p' ).each( function () {

    var $this = $( this );      
        
        
        // Get text, split it up, add spans, put it back together.
        $this.html( 
        
          $.trim( $this.text() )
               .split( /(\s+)/ )
               .map( function ( txt ) {
               
                 // Return text node on whitespace, otherwise wrap text in <span>.
                 if ( /^\s$/.test( txt ) ) {                  
                   return document.createTextNode( ' ' );                    
                 } else {
              
                    var txtLC = txt.toLowerCase(),
                        $word = $( "<span>", {
                          text: txt
                        } )
                        classToApply = 'hover';
                  
                    if ( -1 !== $.inArray( txtLC, alwaysVisible ) ) {
                      classToApply += ' alwaysVisible';
                    }
                  
                    if ( -1 !== $.inArray( txtLC, hiddenAtFirst ) ) {
                      classToApply += ' hiddenAtFirst';
                    }

                    if ( -1 !== $.inArray( txtLC, hiddenAtFirstAndThen ) ) {
                      classToApply += ' hiddenAtFirstAndThen';
                    }
                    
                return $word.addClass( classToApply );
                  
              }

            } )
         
        ); // .html()

  } ).on("mouseout", ".hover", function() {
  
    var $this = $( this );
    
    $this.removeClass( 'hover' ); // Reset.
    
    if ( $this.hasClass( 'hiddenAtFirst' ) ) {
      $this.addClass( 'alwaysVisible' );
    }
    
    if ( $this.hasClass( 'hiddenAtFirstAndThen' ) ) {
      
      $this.fadeOut( 40000 )
           .addClass( 'hover' );
           
    }
    
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
* {
  background-color: black
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10% opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* VISIBLE */

.alwaysVisible,
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.break-word {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.instructions {
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% {
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  }
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.break-word {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.instructions {
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% {
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  }
}

p {
  /* set the animation on p which is the element that have the border */
  -webkit-animation: p 3s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="instructions">
    Place your cursor directly below the arrow, and follow the lines left-to-right. Fullscreen your browser for best effect.
  </div>
  
  <img src="arrow.png">

  <br>

  <div class="story">

    <p>
      "Do you see it?" The Grandmaster calls out, "The Second </p>
    <p> Star?" James did not see the Second Star, not even through the </p>
    <p> telescope, but then again he was never very good at spotting </p>
    <p> constellations. He remembers how his neighbor used to point </p>
    <p> them out to him during neighborhood barbeques. Bulls and </p>
    <p> lions so stolidly sitting in the sky. Those beasts you often hear </p>
    <p> about in the Bible. When you actually saw them-at the zoo </p>
    <p> or something-they looked quite pitiable and stupid. This is not </p>
    <p> like that; this is science. No mythologies, characters or </p>
    <p> rhymes; only astronomy and physics. "We see it!" Calls out </p>
    <p> a young woman, about his own age. Her voice is smooth and </p>
    <p> bursting with piety. She and some other folks are dancing </p>
    <p> around, giddy at the coming transformation. She's not </p>
    <p> extraordinarily pretty-none of them are really-but the glow of </p>
    <p> their joy, the pure bliss that shines off of them in every </p>
    <p> direction makes fine nymphs out of them. The childish spirits </p>
    <p> spin around and giggle, jumping like stray flames from the </p>
    <p> bonfire that had burned earlier. He admires them deeply. </p>
    <p> He is a very large man, and although he has been working</p>
    <p> toward letting his spirit fly free, he is not yet able to dance </p>
    <p> with such blaze. "Come here children! Settle down!" The </p>
    <p> Grandmaster shouts, wiping his brow. "Do you know why we </p>
    <p> live out here?" he pauses, seemingly inhabited by some </p>
    <p> wayward astral-flower, and sniffs. "Well, alright I'll tell you. </p>
    <p> You see, the city is blinding; wayward light leaks from every </p>
    <p> window." His voice softens, and he looks at us as a father </p>
    <p> would, "And so here we are, come to a place of peace; where </p>
    <p> the infinite pinched points of the universe, stream along in a </p>
    <p> dance of profound revelry. Where power doesn't exist except </p>
    <p> for the collective power. Come to me. Let's hold each other </p>
    <p> now." Two women rush to either side of the Grandmaster </p>
    <p> eagerly, as if trying to catch a butterfly. The whole group grabs </p>
    <p> ahold of each other, however they can. Even though there are </p>
    <p> at least eleven people between him and the Grandmaster, </p>
    <p> James can still feel the tendrils of energy reach him through </p>
    <p> the others. It feels warm and exact. His body reverberates with </p>
    <p> the excitation. He feels himself drawing closer to the </p>
    <p>
      frequency of their leader-the Natural Frequency. "The light is </p>
    <p> coming to carry us children! We shall soon ascend and </p>
    <p> transcend. As both particle and wave we will rise from this </p>
    <p> earth. As the ultimate purveyor of knowledge-we shall </p>
    <p> become light itself, if only we prepare our bodies to reach the </p>
    <p> Natural Frequency." His face and voice darken at once, "While </p>
    <p> the unattuned become the less than dark, the nothing they have </p>
    <p> always secretly known themselves to be." Moans of agreement </p>
    <p> and ecstasy echo between the Children and the Grandmaster.</p>
    <p> The energy compounds between them. The Resonance is </p>
    <p> beginning. The Second Star and the First Star have grown </p>
    <p> closer. They are almost exactly seven light-years apart now. </p>
    <p> The Grandmaster tells them that this is the perfect distance </p>
    <p> away. Tonight the combination of their light will produce the </p>
    <p> Perfect Wave, a wave of light that contains frequencies in </p>
    <p> perfect alignment with the frequency of both an electron and</p>
    <p> a proton-the Natural Frequency. The rest of the world will </p>
    <p> fade, but the Children will join the light due to their perfect </p>
    <p> attunement. "The world is so dark," the Grandmaster begins </p>
    <p> again, sobbing, "It's so dark. It's just not fair." The rest of the </p>
    <p> group begins to cry as well. Their passionate moans have </p>
    <p> turned to despairing wails. James too sheds a few tears. He </p>
    <p> couldn't convince them. They wouldn't come with him. "We </p>
    <p> tried to free them Children. We really did try our best. But it's </p>
    <p> time to go. Let's swallow them down and begin the </p>
    <p> Attunement." James looks at the Attunement Agent in his </p>
    <p> hand, designed by the Grandmaster himself to allow the </p>
    <p> frequencies of his body to merge with the Natural Frequency. </p>
    <p> He puts the pill in his mouth, and takes a swig from the </p>
    <p> water bottle that someone has evidently handed him. As he </p>
    <p> throws his head back to swallow the pill, he sees the stars, </p>
    <p> mutely dinging in the sky. He feels very, very good now.</p>
    <p class="break-word">**************************************************************************************************************************************************************</p>
    <p> James wakes up. There is still a world. He is not light, but he </p>
    <p> is still something. He misses the feeling he felt before. Again </p>
    <p> hungry for the flesh of imagined sweetings, he rises to his feet. </p>
    <p> They feel very heavy. He takes off his shoes and ties the </p>
    <p> shoelaces together and they dangle from his fingertips, like </p>
    <p> dice on a rear view mirror, as he wanders through a forest </p>
    <p> unknown to him. He moves towards what little bonfire smoke </p>
    <p> remained from the campsite. The sun is up, but just barely. As </p>
    <p> he walks he sees the other children, some of them huddled </p>
    <p> together, still sleeping, with smiles on their faces. Others look </p>
    <p> a lot like him, wandering around aimlessly. He is too afraid to </p>
    <p> speak to them. The energy is gone. They are all still here. We </p>
    <p> are all still here. Very still. Where is the grandmaster? Has he </p>
    <p> ascended? If he had ascended, why are the children still here? </p>
    <p> Why is everything still here? He comes out of the woods, into </p>
    <p> the clearing where they have built their houses. There is no </p>
    <p> music playing, as there so often was. It is beginning to rain. </p>
    <p> Good for the crops. He eyes the grandmaster's treehouse. He has </p>
    <p> never been there. Grandmaster always told them that they </p>
    <p> should not visit his lodging unless it was an absolute </p>
    <p> emergency. And even then, if Daydream was available, they </p>
    <p> were supposed to tell her and she was to summon him. But if </p>
    <p> there ever was an emergency, this was it. Striding towards the </p>
    <p> abode of the mistaken soothsayer, he tries to project confidence </p>
    <p> as best as he can, but he is sure it is not working. He arrives at </p>
    <p> the bottom of the rope ladder, and calls up to the grandmaster. </p>
    <p> "Grandmaster!" He is surprised to hear his own voice; he had </p>
    <p>not heard it by itself for so long. It does not sound the way that </p>
    <p> he remembered it. But there is no response. He yells louder, but </p>
    <p> still no reply. He looks around warily, seeing only wayward </p>
    <p> children still dwindling around the edge of the woods, unsure of </p>
    <p> how to continue. He drops his shoes and takes a step onto the </p>
    <p>
      ladder. He struggles even to balance on the first rung, but </p>
    <p> pushes up. Swinging back and forth, he forces himself to reach </p>
    <p> the top. He places his elbows on the floorboards, and peers </p>
    <p> through the open door. There the grandmaster sits. His throat </p>
    <p> laughing blood, Daydream sleeping forever in his arms. James </p>
    <p> falls. It's about a six foot drop. Nothing terrible, but air seems </p>
    <p> to flit away from him with each breath now. He lays on his </p>
    <p> back. The oxygen is coming back to him, a tempestuous sylph </p>
    <p> seeming sometimes to tempt him with an especially full breath</p>
    <p> before teasing away again. But as he lays, it comes back to him. </p>
    <p> It gets easier and by the end he breathes easily, his own form of </p>
    <p> meditation. Some time passes, he is not sure how much, before </p>
    <p> he rises to his feet. He is not sure whether he is in shock, but the </p>
    <p> pain of the fall seems to have displaced the horror of what he </p>
    <p> had seen. He goes back to his quarters, an old school bus that he </p>
    <p> shares with about eight other men as living quarters. The </p>
    <p> steering wheel was still attached, but the bus did not drive. Idly, </p>
    <p> he sits and gives the steering wheel a turn or two. One man lays </p>
    <p> on his mat, blissful and unconscious, like a stuffed animal. He </p>
    <p> must have made his way back in the technicolor stupor. Habit is </p>
    <p> a powerful hand to hold. Again, James is too afraid to wake </p>
    <p> him, too afraid to speak to him. He does not know these people. </p>
    <p> He only knows the grandmaster, and he has gone. James sits </p>
    <p> incredulous in the seat of the bus. A riddling strand of accordion </p>
    <p> rain weeps across the window, leaving behind it a trail of </p>
    <p>
      self-fragments before breaking up into nothing. The silence </p>
    <p> which at first oppressed him, seemed to conjure up a kind of </p>
    <p> peace within him now. There was no silence before. No matter </p>
    <p> how early you woke up. Always people singing, yelling, </p>
    <p> chanting their mantras, or perhaps the grandmaster would be </p>
    <p> giving a sermon. He had a booming voice, one that really got </p>
    <p> under your skin and frisked your spirit. But now, the noise </p>
    <p> subsided, James can think again. He thinks first about how he </p>
    <p> has no wallet, no ID, no social security number, no cellphone </p>
    <p> and how there’s no landline. He then thinks about how he's not </p>
    <p> sure how to get home, or if there still is a home. He hasn't talked </p>
    <p> to his mother or father in years. They probably would not have </p>
    <p> missed him anyway. What is there for him, out there? But then, </p>
    <p> what is here? He peers out the window. It seems that the </p>
    <p> children have discovered the untimely death of the grandmaster. </p>
    <p> They are tearing anything and everything apart. They are </p>
    <p> pulling the crops up, biting them and then spitting them onto </p>
    <p> the ground. The shepherd has gone, and the sheep have grown </p>
    <p> rabid in his absence. James isn't quite sure what to do. So he </p>
    <p> just holds the steering wheel of the old school bus, and turns it. </p>
    <p> Round and round, round and round.</p>
  </div>
```

#### Tips

- `div` is not allowed in the head, only [**metadata content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content) is allowed. Move it to the `body` as `head` isn't visible.
- In your JS, don't do `$( this )` all the time, cache it. i.e. `var $this = $( this )`.
- Trim your text so you don't create a bunch of empty `span` elements. i.e. `var txt = $.trim( $this.text() );`. This is due to white space in your document between angled brackets and when your text starts/ends. Those extra spans may or may not cause an issue at some point. Depends on styles applied.